# Unable to append 2 1D arrays in 1 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Below is my code where I'm trying to append 2 1D arrays to a 1 1D array:

```
import numpy as np
import random

arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(1,))
arr1 = np.random.randint(20, size=(1,))
arr2 = np.random.randint(30, size=(1,))

print(arr)
print(arr1)
print(arr2)

aparr = np.append(arr, arr1, arr2)
print(aparr)
```

However, I'm getting an error saying:

```
     21 print(arr2)
     22 
---> 23 aparr = np.append(arr, arr1, arr2)
     24 print(aparr)

<__array_function__ internals> in append(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in append(arr, values, axis)
   4669         values = ravel(values)
   4670         axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 4671     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
   4672 
   4673 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Not sure, what am I missing/doing wrong. Can someone please take a look and point/explain the mistake by correcting the piece of code?

Comment: Did you go back and reread the `append` docs?  Is the signature clear?  `append(arr, values, axis)`?  What is the 3rd argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the command you are looking for is called [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)
That is what is commonly used to combine multiple arrays into one array of the same dimension.

```
arr = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,))
arr1 = np.random.randint(20, size=(10,))
arr2 = np.random.randint(30, size=(5,))
combined = np.concatenate([arr, arr1, arr2]) # will be of size 25
```

notice that all the arrays are in one list (can be tuple or something else, as long as it is passed as one variable to the function).

It is possible to use `np.append`, but that is just a limited version of `np.concatenate` as can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/b31a3a3fb05910abc2ee55d63255efdb2a2c383e/numpy/ma/core.py#L8243), and it only works when combining exactly two arrays, so you would have to do it in two steps or by combining the two arrays which should be added:

```
combined = np.append(np.append(arr, arr1), arr2)
# OR 
combined = np.append(arr, [arr1, arr2])
```

The final alternative works because the arrays are flattened before combining, because `axis` (what dimension to combine the two arrays along) is not specified.

Answer (score 3):

np.append() takes two arguments, an array to append to and a list of values to append to it. So, replace

```
aparr = np.append(arr, arr1, arr2)
```

by

```
aparr = np.append(arr, [arr1, arr2])
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, I was about to post the same as I just found the same thing with testing it out. Seems you are bit faster than me.Thanks again